# Any suggestions on how could I solve this integral involving a square-root of a polynomial in the denominator?

Tags: integration

This is not a homework problem, so there is no guarantee that this integral is solvable analytically. 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2(1-x/2)}{\sqrt{x^2(1-x/2)^2+b}}dx\,.
$$

It looks simple enough, but the fact that the (1-x/2) term in the denominator is squared seems to thwart any attempt at 'u' or trig substitution. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: Changed dt to dx.

Comment: Well, you have a cubic in the numerator and a quadratic in the denominator, so it probably doesn't converge.

Comment: Did you mean dx insteaf of dt? Because this is very easy if its dt

Comment: [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) can't do anything with this, so I doubt there is any analytical solution.

Comment: This looks more like it wants to go from $0$ to $2$...

Comment: @vonbrand: it is interesting that maxima didn't say that the integral diverges.

Comment: Where did the integral arise? Please edit the question to include additional background and motivation. Also, please include a description of what you have already tried. These things help make the question more compelling, help others find it, and help others write more useful answers.

Comment: @TravisJ, which is what I said.

Comment: @TravisJ I said **quadratic** which is $x^2$.

Comment: @AJStas, my apologies... quadratic and quartic look too similar.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as $x\to\infty$, the integrand is asymptotic to $-x$. Thus, I don't think this integral even converges.